Inverting op amp is not working
I’ve been trying to create an inverting op amp circuit on a breadboard using a 9V battery dual supply, a 100K feedback resistor, a 10K negative input resistor, and a 1.5V input signal at the negative input while positive is grounded. For some reason the circuit is not inverting the input signal, and my meter is also showing that the feedback is not making the negative terminal 0V, but is instead carrying the input voltage to the other side. Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Schematic adapted from "1) Inverting DC Amplifier" at Homemade Circuit Projects - 16 Easy IC 741 Op Amp Circuits Explained

The input signal does not connect to the negative input.

Have you verified the supply voltages while the device operates?

Yes, I checked them with a meter

@NewGuy - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each item. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) please [edit] the question & add each name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the original source was a book or other offline material, please [edit] the question & add the best reference you can e.g. title, author(s), page, edition etc. (See the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules.) TY

Hi New Guy, what Sam wrote does not mean "remove the very relevant schematic", it means "add an explicit link to the source". But we can make this short: We see "swagatam innovations" on a lot of really really bad schematics posted to this site, mostly by students from the Indian subcontinent. You can have a rule of thumb: If a schematic is colorful and carries a watermark in the middle, it means that someone stole it without understanding it, because their main focus is directing traffic to their website, and not electronics. Find a better source for information and circuitry.

(this is an example of a really really bad schematic. On multiple fronts, but it starts with using a 741 opamp, grounding one input and then having a series resistor to the input, lack of decoupling, … the whole thing is a fractal of "someone copied this schematic but they have never understood what they're doing, so basically everything is wrong")

SamGibson- Ok I did.

@NewGuy no, you did not. A proper source link is a link to the actual page containing the schematic, not just to a web domain. While adding that useless domain name, you broke your post by removing the picture, so I had to undo your change, too.

@NewGuy - Hi, As I explained above, a reference should give the website name, page title & link, as shown in the example in the site rule which I linked. Just adding a website home page URL is inadequate (and that edit removed the image, as kindly explained & fixed by Marcus). As you are seeing, we take things a bit more seriously here, than some forums e.g. the inclusion of copied / adapted material from elsewhere without correct & clear referencing, breaks the Code of Conduct.

(continued) Oh dear, while I've been typing, you deleted the adapted schematic again :( It's a relevant part of your question, so you've added work for other people who will have to find the source of the image. I've found (what I think is) the original source and which you then adapted, so I'll add the correct reference for you. Please avoid vandalising your posts in future. TY

SamGibson- Appreciate it. Sorry, not very familiar with the internet.

MarcusMüller- I am currently learning electronics through a book called Practical Electronics for Inventors, and I made this circuit from a schematic in the book as an attempt to understand op amps.

Marcus, do you not know why there is a resistor in series between the non-inverting input and GND?

@AnalogKid with the high, assymetric leakage currents of a 741? I'm not sure I do!

To me it looks like whoever did the schematic had a bit of classical training about balancing input bias currents.  Maybe not necessary in this application, but hardly a component of a "bad schematic."

@AnalogKid fair! But: whoever did the schematic definitely had no contact whatsoever with who put it on the website that New Guy found it on.

Your circuit gain is -10. -10 x +1.5 = -15 V. How can the amp make -15 v out with a -9 V supply?
Also, there is a phenomenon in old opamps where the output inverts if the part is overdriven.  That might be happening in your case.
Change R1 to 10K to see if the circuit inverts the input correctly.  Don't worry about gain until you get that part working.
Also, add a 0.1 uF ceramic power supply decoupling capacitor across the power pins (4 and 7).  Keep the leads as short as possible.
Update:
While all opamps have issues and limitations, the 741 has more than most.  You have to deal with bandwidth, input common mode voltage range, output stage headroom limitations, noise, crossover distortion, and relatively high input bias currents and input offset voltage.  All of these things will come up using more contemporary components, and the 741 is the perfect part for learning all about them.

I changed the resistor and added the capacitor, but the output is still reading the same voltage as the input.
